# Handling left-to-right inside right-to-left paragraphs using Emacs and AUCTeX

Tags: latex, auctex, right-to-left, bidirectional-support

I'm using Emacs to typeset a document which has English as its main language but which will use Hebrew and Greek as well.

You can see on my screenshot how the `\footnote` command shows two open brackets as opposed to the correct open and close brackets.

```latex
{\footnoteA{This is a Hebrew related footnote
```

as opposed to the correct way

```latex
\footnoteA{This is a Hebrew related footnote}
```

The end result however, on the PDF is correct.

[image: Incorrect handling of left-to-right text within a right-to-left paragraph]

This is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek, hebrew}
\setmainfont{SBL BibLit}
\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{hebrew}
  \pstart

בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית\footnoteA{This is a Hebrew related footnote} בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃

  \pend
\end{hebrew}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{greek}
  \pstart
  Ἐν ἀρχῇ\footnoteA{This is a Greek related footnote} ἐποίησεν ὁ
  θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν.
  \pend
\end{greek}
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Column
\end{document}
```

Note how the text a line of Hebrew with mixed English characters is rendered correctly when edited using TextEdit (i.e. test editor that comes with MacOS)

[image]

Comment: I thought that inserting `LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK` and `RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK` (see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Bidirectional-Display.html) would have helped, but I can't make it work.  For the record, this problem appears with most TeX editors, including TeXstudio, Texmaker, TeXworks, but not with `vi` which is able to correctly render the text out-of-the-box, oops.

Comment: A follow up on this. To make it work we warp the phrase with LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (on both ends). After that is done the visual display corrects itself. It works beautifully!

Comment: Please answer your own question, so other people can benefit from this solution `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've since find out that wrapping the phrase on both ends with the LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK gives the desired result. To do that position your cursor appropriately and `C-x 8 RET LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK`. The visual display will fix itself and the text will be shown correctly.

Comment: The LEFT-TO-RIGHT mark can be typed with Shift-ט on the Lyx Hebrew keyboard.